# I am getting this error after installing @react-navigation/stack

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-stack, stack-navigator

[I am getting this error after installing @react-navigation/stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iz0Ov.jpg)

Comment: if you are running on iOS after installing. You need to run pod install again and close the bundler and run again.

Comment: I am using Android Emulator